# How to create sub-dictionaries without overwriting each entry?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

```
east = {"George Street": "52.1382238, -0.4496112", 
        "Barnstable Road": "52.143864, -0.4474769", 
        "Newnham Avenue": "52.1367876, -0.4448371"}
mainzone = {"Anglia Cars": "52.138622, -0.466633",
            "Bedford train station": "52.135694, -0.478704", 
            "Swan hotel": "52.134863, -0.465163"}

MainToEast = {}
for key in dict.items(mainzone):
    for i in dict.items(east):
        varFrom = key[1]
        varTo = i[1]
        MainToEast.update({key[0]: {i[0]: '£4.00'}})
```

Every time this loop runs, it 'updates' the dict set instead of adding the new values (which are dictionaries).

I've tried `.setdefault` for the first key but it does the same thing. I'm sure it's a problem with the loop but can't figure it out.

#### Expected result:

```
{'Anglia Cars': {'George Street': '£4.00'}, 
                {'Barnstable Road': '£4.00'}, 
                {'Newnham Avenue': '£4.00'}}....
{'Bedford train station': {'George Street': '£4.00'}, 
                          {'Barnstable Road': '£4.00'}, 
                          {'Newnham Avenue': '£4.00'}}....
```

The output must be in this format. Not a list inside a dictionary. I'm using the dataset in a dataframe which won't accept the latter dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key ofthe  problem is that you are using the `update` method where you actually want to add a new key to the dictionary. `dict.update()` updates the value of a given key if it is already present in the dict. If the key is not present `dict.update()` adds it. In the following example a `dict` is created, which holds a key called 'x' and its corresponding value 1234. The call to `abc.update` 
updates the vale of `x` because 'x' is already an existing key of `abc`. It also adds the new key 'y' to `abc` since it is not yet part of `abc`.

```
abc = {'x': 1234}
abc.update({'x': 999, 'y': 222})
# result: {'x': 999, 'y': 222}
```

To add a new key and corresponding value to a dictionary, you would use the pattern `dict_name[key] = value`. To add a new key/value pair ('z', 17) to the above dictionary `abc` you would write:

```
abc['z'] = 17
```

In order to iterate over the items it is not necessary to create a dictionary items object from the items of your dictionary, simply because they are already dictionary items. So you would rather do the following in your loops:

```
for key in mainzone.items():
    ...
```

However, iterating using the `.items()` method yields a tuple `(key, value)`. That's why have to write `key[0]`, to get the desired key. But you only need the key and not the value, so it would be better to simply iterate over the dictionaries keys:

```
for val in mainzone.keys():
    ...
```

In Python you don't want to use "CamelCase" for variable names, since it is reserved for classes. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) for more information on this. Instead use all lower case with an underscore as separator.

Additionally it would be appropriate to store the coordinates as tuple of floats instead of strings., because that's what they are: a pair of numbers. You would choose a tuple a not a list because tuples are immutable objects and you don't want you coordinates to be changed.
So, here is a working example that solves your problem:

```
east = {
    "George Street": (52.1382238, -0.4496112), 
    "Barnstable Road": (52.143864, -0.4474769), 
    "Newnham Avenue": (52.1367876, -0.4448371)}

mainzone = {
    "Anglia Cars": (52.138622, -0.466633),
    "Bedford train station": (52.135694, -0.478704),
    "Swan hotel": (52.134863, -0.465163)}


main_to_east = {}
for main_station in mainzone.keys():
    main_to_east[main_station] = {east_station: '£4.00' for east_station in east.keys()}
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much... I knew that's why the `.update` wasn't working I just couldn't figure out a way to add the values. Also the `.items` to `.keys` is also gold.

The reason why the numbers are in string format is because they must be passed through an API call which can only take a string value as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Expected output data structure is invalid. You probably need a dict of list.

**Ex:**(using `dict.setdefault`)

```
east = {"George Street": "52.1382238, -0.4496112", 
"Barnstable Road": "52.143864, -0.4474769", "Newnham Avenue": "52.1367876, -0.4448371"}
mainzone = {"Anglia Cars": "52.138622, -0.466633",
 "Bedford train station": "52.135694, -0.478704", "Swan hotel": "52.134863, -0.465163"}

MainToEast = {}

for key in mainzone:
    for sub_key in east:
        MainToEast.setdefault(key, []).append({sub_key: '£4.00'})

print(MainToEast)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Anglia Cars': [{'George Street': '£4.00'},
                 {'Barnstable Road': '£4.00'},
                 {'Newnham Avenue': '£4.00'}],
 'Bedford train station': [{'George Street': '£4.00'},
                           {'Barnstable Road': '£4.00'},
                           {'Newnham Avenue': '£4.00'}],
 'Swan hotel': [{'George Street': '£4.00'},
                {'Barnstable Road': '£4.00'},
                {'Newnham Avenue': '£4.00'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; the problem I have is that I can't have the second dictionary as a list as i'm using pandas. The {'Anglia Cars': {'George Street': '£4.00'} format is imperative otherwise I get ValueError: arrays must all be same length when I run a dataframe with that dataset

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using **`list` / `dict` comprehension**.  Not sure if this logic meets your requirements, but might be of assistance to someone else looking at this post.

```
east = {"George Street": "52.1382238, -0.4496112", 
        "Barnstable Road": "52.143864, -0.4474769", 
        "Newnham Avenue": "52.1367876, -0.4448371"}
mainzone = {"Anglia Cars": "52.138622, -0.466633",
            "Bedford train station": "52.135694, -0.478704", 
            "Swan hotel": "52.134863, -0.465163"}

# Create a list of dicts for your sub-keys.
subs = [{i: '£4.00'} for i in east]
# Add the sub-key to each main key.
MainToEast = {i: sub for i in mainzone}
```

#### Output:

```
{'Anglia Cars': [{'George Street': '£4.00'},
                 {'Newnham Avenue': '£4.00'},
                 {'Barnstable Road': '£4.00'}],
 'Bedford train station': [{'George Street': '£4.00'},
                           {'Newnham Avenue': '£4.00'},
                           {'Barnstable Road': '£4.00'}],
 'Swan hotel': [{'George Street': '£4.00'},
                {'Newnham Avenue': '£4.00'},
                {'Barnstable Road': '£4.00'}]}
```

Comment: It produces a result but not the result that is expected or required nks for the reply; the problem I have is that I can't have the second dictionary as a list as i'm using pandas. The {'Anglia Cars': {'George Street': '£4.00'} format is imperative otherwise I get ValueError: arrays must all be same length when I run a dataframe with that dataset